# Forward Iterator - Const version issue

Tags: c++, iterator, forward-list

I can't seem a way to fix this issue. I have implemented a templated forward iterator that I'd like to also use as const_iterator in my ForwardList class. What I tried so far is using an alias, and insert `const` as template argument, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my forward iterator:

```
    template<typename T>
    class forward_iterator {
    private:
        Node<T>* m_iterator;

    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using reference = T&;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

        constexpr forward_iterator(Node<T>* forw_iter) : m_iterator{ forw_iter } {}

        constexpr Node<T>* getNodeAddress() const noexcept { return m_iterator; }
        constexpr Node<T>* getNodeNextAddress() const noexcept { return m_iterator->next; }
        constexpr reference operator*() const noexcept { return m_iterator->data; }
        constexpr pointer operator->() const noexcept { return m_iterator; }
        constexpr forward_iterator& operator++() noexcept {
            m_iterator = m_iterator->next;
            return *this;
        }
        constexpr forward_iterator operator++(int) noexcept {
            forward_iterator tmp(*this);
            m_iterator = m_iterator->next;
            return tmp;
        }
        constexpr friend bool operator== (const forward_iterator& first, const forward_iterator& second) noexcept { return (first.m_iterator == second.m_iterator); }
        constexpr friend bool operator!=(const forward_iterator& first, const forward_iterator& second) noexcept { return !(first.m_iterator == second.m_iterator); }
    };
```

And this is how I use the aliases in the ForwardList class:

```
template<typename Type>
    class ForwardList {
    private:
        Node<Type>* m_head;
        Node<Type>* m_tail;
        std::size_t m_size{};       

    public:
        using value_type = Type;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using reference = value_type&;
        using const_reference = const value_type&;
        using pointer = Type*;
        using const_pointer = const pointer;
        using iterator = forward_iterator<value_type>;
        using const_iterator = forward_iterator<const Type>;
```

This is the node struct:

```
    template<typename T>
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node() = default;
        constexpr explicit Node(const T& data)
            : data{ data } {}
    };
```

I get an error when I use const_iterator though. For example:

```
constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept {
            return const_iterator(m_head);
        }
```

^ In the iterator functions, I get "`Cannot convert from container::Node<Type> *const   to container::forward_iterator<const Type>`.

Another example:

```
constexpr iterator emplace_after(const_iterator position, Args...args)
```

^ In emplace_after, I can't pass in a normal "list.begin()" iterator, because the function cannot be found. I have to instead pass "list.cbegin()".

If anyone coud help be understand what's wrong that'd be fantastic.

Comment: Please be sure to put any compiler errors in code blocks as well. I had to edit your question because it was treating `<Type>` and `<const Type>` as HTML blocks, and so they were just ignored and not displayed

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but the problem is that you cannot pass a pointer of `Node<Type>` to a function accepting a pointer of `Node<const Type>*`. Different template specializations (even just CV-qualified) are fundamentally different types as far as C++ is concerned -- so you will need to change the way your `forward_iterator` is designed to accommodate this

Comment: `using NodeT = std::condition_t<std::is_const_v<Type>,const Node<std::remove_const_t<Type>>, Node<Type>>;` maybe?

Comment: I have tried that just yesterday @MooingDuck. Did not seem to fix my issues, unfortunately. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @SomeoneWithPassion [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab19c1c884c3c60f)

Comment: @MooingDuck I see: I was missing to use the alias in the ctor too. That worked perfectly, thank you a lot! So the issue was with the Node struct that wasn't able to accept a const T, so I have to remove the const with std::remove_const. Is that right? Thanks again!

Comment: The problem was that `Node<T>` can't be converted to a `Node<const T>`, so I used `std::remove_const` to make _all_ of the `Node` objects be `Node<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below makes your `forward_iterator<const T>` point at a `Node<const T>` while the `forward_iterator<T>` will point at a `Node<T>`. Both should point at a `Node<T>` whether `T` is `const` or not itself:

```
template<typename T>
class forward_iterator {
private:
    Node<T>* m_iterator;
```

I find it easier to create the iterator as a class template inside the container class template so that the original `T` is available. If you want to do it outside the class, you could add a template parameter to your iterator template:

```
template<typename OrigT, typename T>
class forward_iterator {
private:
    Node<OrigT>* m_iterator;

public:
    constexpr forward_iterator_impl(Node<OrigT>* forw_iter) : m_iterator{ forw_iter } {}
    ...
```

And in the container class template:

```
template<typename Type>
class ForwardList {
public:
    ...
    using iterator = forward_iterator<value_type, value_type>;
    using const_iterator = forward_iterator<value_type, const value_type>;
```

By moving both the node and the iterator into the container class. It becomes easier to get it right. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jYeGeM)

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you. I will try to implement it as a subclass as you posted. Why does that work, what's the difference with having the iterator inside ForwardList and having it ouside? Thank you!

Comment: @SomeoneWithPassion No real difference, but it's less typing since both `T` and `IterType` is available. Note though that in this implementation a `const_iterator` and an `iterator` isn't comparable. That's easy to fix though.

Comment: Ah, I see. Indeed, it did not fix my two issues. Do you have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, the code seems to have changed since I copied it from your post. I must have copied it during the first minutes after you posted :-)

Comment: @SomeoneWithPassion I made an update to make the `const_iterator` and `iterator` comparable. I don't get an error in `constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return const_iterator(m_head);  }` with this setup.

Comment: I have already fixed the issue thanks to user MooingDuck. However, since you were really quick with your answer and it's also helpful as it fixed the issue, I'll mark your answer as Solved. Thanks!

Comment: @SomeoneWithPassion Oh, thanks. :-) I made a demo of what I find easiest when doing things like this.